# recommened xml, xpath tools for J2ME

Tags: java, xml, xpath, java-me

We are start working with J2ME application where we need the XML parsers based SAX, DOM and Xpath navigation support.

I found kXML recommended by many developers. What are other free/open source libraries available you found useful and using in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [minixpath](http://minixpath.sourceforge.net/) once. Does simple things and is lightweight. It uses [kxml](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/) internally.